# How to load an earlier version of jQuery onto a page of a newer Wordpress Site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an older jQuery plugin that I really like, and it works fine in a basic HTML web page, but not very well when I try to bring it into a WordPress page that's probably using a newer version of jQuery.

In particular, my WordPress site (version 3.7.1) is making use of a newer jQuery library, while the plugin is based on an earlier jquery-1.6.2.js library.

In the functions.php file of my site I've tried using the following code to bring

- the necessary CSS,
- the 1.6.2 javascript library, and
- the plugin's javascript file into the `<head>` section of the web page:

```
function test_enqueue_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.popeye', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.popeye.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.popeye.style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.popeye.style.css',false,'1.1','all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_enqueue_css' );


function get_jquery_library() {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.6.2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery-1.6.2.js',false,'1.1','all');    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_jquery_library', 1);


function test_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.popeye-2.1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.popeye-2.1.js',false,'1.1','all');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_enqueue_script' );
```

The css work well, but the JS doesn't. Can anyone suggest a way for me to load an earlier version of jQuery onto a site that has a newer version of jQuery?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the plugin is using 1.6.2, making it compatible with the latest will be relatively easy. simply include the jquery migrate plugin before your plugin.

Comment: get the older plugin code and upgrade it, it's not that hard